# Email Client using Spring

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I am looking to build an email client using Spring in Java to hopefully get some experience using the Spring framework. Would I be best off using the JavaMail library or the Email library that is part of the Spring framework?

I have no experience with either, just wondered what the best option would be. I mainly want to learn Spring in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spring mail library is just a thin wrapper around the JavaMail API. It's considerably easier to use than the raw API.

It's not a core part of Spring, though, and won't really teach you much about how Spring works.

Answer (score 1):

Skaffman is correct Spring has its own mail library.

I think you are taking the right approach. The key to learning and understanding any framework is to use it and build something you are interested in.

You can easily build a thick client mail application in Spring. Beyond the mail API, you will gain experience using the bean container, dependency injection, spring annotations, and numerous other features. As your project grows you can pick other features of Spring that interest you and identify problems for your solution.

Remember Spring is a pocket knife framework. You may not(and probably should not) use all of it. The best place for information regarding spring is the Docs(available at [springsource.org](http://springsource.org))